# Extracting values from matrix to add to a dataframe column using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I am using `mutate` to add a fifth (h) and sixth column (d) to my data frame containing 37975 rows and 4 columns names i,j,k,x. For d, I am picking values from a matrix which was basically a raster. Addition of this column (d) is causing problems. I receive the following error when I try to view the dataframe.

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.3 Gb Error: no more error
> handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

I use the following code to do this:

```
   vxfile <- vxfile %>% 
   select(1:4) %>% 
   mutate(h = k+as.numeric(sub(".*\\s","",txt)),
          d = as.vector(dt_mat[35-j, i+1]))
```

When I check lengths of the columns, column d is different. It is 1442100625 (37975 x 37975) while others are obviously 37975

When I check the class of each columns, column d is `"matrix" "array"` and others are `numeric`

When I check the `str(vxfile)`, column d is `$ d       : num [1:37975, 1:37975] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`

Clearly the problem is with how I am picking the value from the matrix. Could someone explain why this is causing this problem?

I tried `dt_mat[cbind(35-j, i+1)]` and it seems to be working

Comment: I think your issue is that `mutate()` is going to pass in a vector `j` and a vector `i`, thus returning not what you want from the `dt_mat`. What *might* work (can't test it) is if you use `d = purrr::map2_dbl(i, j, ~ dt_mat[35 - .y, .x + 1])` (assuming the return is numeric). Not sure if that will be slow though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! `cbind` solved the issue for me and I was wondering how exactly. My understanding of the `map` related functions is very limited. Will try it!

Comment: It has to do with how `mutate` is vectorizing. It is passing in the 37975 row vector `i` into your statement. So you can see how it is selecting a 37975 x 37975 matrix as the result. The `map2` line is forcing it to feed in the values row-by-row, probably yielding what you want. Similar to `rowwise`, but I find it more streamlined.